# bclogo todonotes clash

Tags: packages, incompatibility, todonotes, bclogo

The following MWE generates an error (but produces correct output).  What is the easiest work-around?

`Argument of \reserved@a has an extra } Hello\todo{\bcsmbh}`

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{bclogo}


\begin{document}

Hello\todo{\bcsmbh}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind: a `\protect` before `\bcsmbh` does the trick.

Comment: It begs the question though, why these commands are not *protected* in the package itself.

Comment: lazy latex programmers? ;-) If you need `\bcsmbh` often, you should think about `\robustify\bcsmbh` (using `etoolbox` as package for `\robustify`)

Comment: All `\bc...` seem to be just wrappers for `\includegraphics`, which has an optional argument, so this falls apart if `\protect` is not used